# GC Collection problem

Tags: c#-4.0, garbage-collection

I am converting a byte array into a BitmapSource. My routine works, I can put a breakpoint on "return dest;" see the value and it's properties for a few seconds and then it times out and I can't access any more properties. Is this getting GC'd? Any ideas how to fix this?

```
    public static class ImageConversion
{
    public static BitmapSource ConvertByteArrayToBitmapSource(Byte[] imageBytes, ImageFormat formatOfImage)
    {
        BitmapSource dest;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.Length);
            var decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            dest = decoder.Frames[0];
        }

        return dest;
    } }
```

Comment: Is it `dest` you can't see anymore? Or is it `imageBytes`, `stream`, or `decoder`?

Comment: Looking at it more I think I'm sending the decoder invalid info. It's just that I read something about the decoder, a memory stream and GC. So when I saw it flake out in the debugger after a moment I thought it might have been a GC issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory referenced by `dest` won't get garbage collected until it's unrooted.  As long as you have some variable referencing that memory (including the `dest` variable itself) it won't get collected.

This is more likely a debugger issue, not a GC issue.